# Has a STEM professor ever won an Oscar?

Tags: career-path, industry, academic-life, awards

Has a STEM professor ever been nominated for - or won - an Oscar for their academic research?

Comment: Do the technical Oscars count? I'd be *very* surprised if there weren't a few in there...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is the definition of a boat programming question ("Has an <academic> ever done <something that's not at all specific to academia>").

Comment: [Richard Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Taylor_(filmmaker)) has won several oscars, but not [that Richard Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Taylor_(mathematician)).

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question: The question has only triggered answers where the people won their Oscars for their academic achievements. I propose to change the question to ask for this and then reopen it.

Comment: This question might be on topic at:  http://movies.stackexchange.com/  (I'm not a regular there though, so please verify with their moderators/meta/etc before moving.)

Comment: @Dirk This still does not "feel" like an academia question to me. At best it's trivia, and the three answers so far make the question look like a shopping question.

Comment: @user70019 What does trivia about who has won an Oscar to do with "life as graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor"? And given that the question was in the Hot Network Questions list for a while (a random selection), the votes and views mean close to nothing anymore.

Comment: She (Jodie Foster) returned to Yale in 1993 to address the graduating class, and was awarded an honorary Doctor of Fine Arts degree from the university in 1997. - Wikipedia I know it's not exactely STEM but still worth to mentione in a comment.

Comment: UCLA mathematicians Joseph Teran and Alexey Stomakhin (Teran's PhD student at the time) worked on the snow simulation for Frozen, so they at least contributed to a movie that won an oscar.  Stomakhin, now at Disney, worked on Zootopia, which just won an Oscar.  Teran was a student of Ron Fedkiw (who won an Oscar), by the way. Relevant article: http://dailybruin.com/2017/02/24/oscars-2017-alum-creates-software-to-breathe-life-into-moana-zootopia/

Answer (score 25):

Yes.

For example, a professor from Stanford, Rod Fedkiw, won an Oscar in 2015. You can read about it in the following article:

[Stanford professor wins Oscar for science of destroying things](http://abc7news.com/entertainment/stanford-professor-wins-oscar-for-science-of-destroying-things/527926/)

Answer (score 7):

An example of a previous professor winning the *technical Oscar* is [Ken Museth](http://ken.museth.org/Biography.html) (professor at the University of Linköping in Sweden) [who won it together with Peter Cucka and Mihai Aldén](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FwOc4OSOR0) for their work on [OpenVDB](http://www.openvdb.org) in 2014.

Answer (score 1):

[Ken Perlin](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/), a professor of computer science at the NYU Media Research Lab, won a [technical achievement Oscar](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/doc/oscar.html) for the development of [Perlin](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/) [Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise).